# Blazor: removing radio input 'checked' attribute

Tags: blazor

Based on [this guide](https://blazor-university.com/components/code-generated-html-attributes/), when we want to use HTML attributes, such as `readonly` and `disabled` which require no values, we should assign a boolean value to the attribute and razor would render the attribute based on the boolean value(not outputting the attribute if boolean is false and vice versa).

Now suppose we have a group of radio inputs and we want the button `Clear` to clear the selected radio input so that none of the radio inputs get selected (initial state basically).

```
@page "/"

<button @onclick="@(() => isChecked = false)">Clear</button>

<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="option" id="1" value="1"
           checked="@isChecked">
    <label class="form-check-label question-option" for="1">
        option A
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="option" id="2" value="2"
           checked="@isChecked">
    <label class="form-check-label question-option" for="2">
        option B
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="option" id="3" value="3"
           checked="@isChecked">
    <label class="form-check-label question-option" for="3">
        option C
    </label>
</div>


@code {
    private bool isChecked = false;
}
```

`Clear` button does not work because the `isChecked` variable is initialized with `false` value and therefore `checked` and its association (`isChecked`) never got put on the inputs; but how can we remove the `checked` attribute from the inputs?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works

```
@page "/"

<div>
    Selected: @selectedValue
</div>
<button @onclick="@(() => selectedValue = "")">Clear</button>

<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="option" id="1" value="1"
                 checked=@(selectedValue == "1") @onclick=@(() => selectedValue = "1")>
    <label class="form-check-label question-option" for="1">
        option A
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="option" id="2" value="2"
                 checked=@(selectedValue == "2") @onclick=@(() => selectedValue = "2")>
    <label class="form-check-label question-option" for="2">
        option B
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="option" id="3" value="3"
                 checked=@(selectedValue == "3") @onclick=@(() => selectedValue = "3")>
    <label class="form-check-label question-option" for="3">
        option C
    </label>
</div>


@code {
    private string selectedValue;
}
```